# bootstrap button onclick and location.href

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button

Any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick="location.href='http://anothersitehere.com/file.pdf'">Download PDF</button>
```

Comment: As an HTML attribute, onclick should be all lowercase (not onClick).

Comment: Thanks, I've got too much JS on the brain lately. That doesn't fix my issue here though, correct? (just tried it)

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle link?

Comment: If that doesn't fix your issue, then I don't know why it wouldn't, but you might try using `<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="http://anothersitehere.com/file.pdf">Download PDF</a>` instead.

Comment: @Zach yeah both solutions work (onclick= or href=) it was apparently only not working in a wordpress post preview. Once published, either worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that it is working regarding on going to the link. I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: You're right - for some reason it didn't want to work in a WordPress preview. But once I published it - it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You would try with this instead

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="http://anothersitehere.com/file.pdf">
   Download PDF
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving `location.href` blank and in javascript function give

```
document.location.href='page.php?variable='+value;
```

it will redirect to the page you want.